# psycopg2 issue with this installation on ubuntu

Tags: python

I was able to install psycopg2 on my windows machine easily.

I was facing some issue on ubuntu. Based on another answer on stackoverflow, I did this:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

and it went find. But when I run my script, it throw error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

What to do??

Answer (score 0):

First, check python version.
For which version package python-psycopg2? Which python version you run?
Maybe, python-psycopg2 for python2 and you run python3? Then install python3-psycopg2 package.

Comment: python --version ? Is it virtual environment or global?

Comment: virtual env version 3.7

Comment: Thats the problem. Do you create virtual env with ```--system-site-packages```? If no, install psycopg2 in virtual env(need python3-dev, postgresql, libpq-dev) or psycopg2-binary: ```source <venv>/bin/activate && pip install psycopg2-binary```. Or create new virtual env with ```--system-site-packages```.